# How to get edited row index - OnBatchEditOpening

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

In my RadGrid (early 2014 version) I have this:

```
<ClientSettings>
   <ClientEvents OnBatchEditOpening="batchEdit" />
</ClientSettings>
```

Then I have this js function:

```
function batchEditInitialInvestments(sender, args) {
   ...
}
```

This is working great mostly, I can grab (inside the js) the column uniquename that was clicked and other useful properties. I can also get the total number of rows in the grid. What I just can't find is which row was clicked (edited in batch mode), by index. For example, say there are 3 rows in my radgrid and the middle/2nd row is clicked/edited. How can I discover that "index 1" was clicked?

I have scoured the API docs at the following locations:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-getting-familiar-with-client-side-api.html
http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-onbatcheditopening.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the cell of the selected row from the master table view as shown below.

```
function batchEditInitialInvestments(sender, args) {
 var grid = $find('<%=RadGridName.ClientID%>');//can also use the sender parameter
 var master = grid.get_masterTableView();
 var selected = master.get_selectedItems();
 var  row = selected[0];
 var  cell = master.getCellByColumnUniqueName(row, "ColumnUniqueName");
 //cell is the cell of the selected row
```

}